# How can I make ecplise append a "// namespace my_ns" when starting a namespace?

Tags: autocomplete, namespaces, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse CDT, if you type in:

```
namespace my_ns {
```

it completes the `{` with a closing branch, `}` two lines later, and move the cursor to the empty line between.

Is it possible to make Eclipse add

```
} // namespace my_ns
```

i.e. also append a trailing comment?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to make Eclipse itself do that, but with [CppStyle](http://cppstyle.com/) you can get clang-format to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use content assist to declare the namespace. That means:

- Type `namespace` **without** a trailing space or the name you want to use.
- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.
- Type the namespace name.

Voilà! With Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Code Style > Code Templates > Code > End of namespace declaration you can customize the comment.

Notes:

- The namespace code template may *not* trigger if you type in `namespace foo`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. If you type in an opening brace at that point, you will only get a matching closing brace - not the end of a namespace.
- If instead of choosing the namespace code template, a pop-up list is shown, then typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> again will limit the choices to code templates only. The code template `namespace - namespace declaration` is the right one.

Comment: While this seems like it _should_ work - it does not. Whatever I add to the "end of namespace" template - I only get the closing brace. Tried this with the latest Eclipse CDT 2019.3 and with CUDA nsight 9.2.

Comment: Would you try something more? Go to a new line in a .cpp file, write `namespac` without the last `e`, then press `Ctrl+Space`. What completions does the content assist offer? Here it offers four completions, the last of them being the code template proposal. By pressing `Ctrl+Space` again (see last line of the popup) I can switch to **only** showing template proposals. If I choose the code template `namespace - namespace declaration`, then the code is inserted as expected. My suspect is that you get (also?) completions other than the code template offered. But you need the template!!!

Comment: This _does_ work. Would you edit your answer accordingly?

Comment: I have tried to. But to be honest, I am not completely sure what actually has solved the problem. Would you check my edit?

Comment: Ok, I take it back. It appears I had been typing the word "namespace" _with_ a trailing space, ignoring your instruction. My "finger memory" was kicking in. In fact, both of your suggestions work. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: No problem. :-) I will leave the edit, since it does no harm.